# MySQL: Create Function, Execute statement and Drop function

Tags: mysql, create-function

I have wrote mysql query to update column using mysql variable. Actually I'm want to **create the function, execute it and then drop the function** for below query. I'm really new to mysql Function, Can some please help me to covert query into mySQL Function.

```
SET @user_id = 1;
SET @user_employee_id_new = '87847894';
SET @user_employee_id_old = '35345642';
select * from `user` WHERE (`employee` = @user_employee_id_new);
select @user_id = id from `user` WHERE (`employee` = @user_employee_id_old);
UPDATE `user` SET `employee` = @user_employee_id_new WHERE id = @user_id;
```

Appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: a function is used , when you need to make computations repeatedly, so  you write it once and use it for ever

Comment: It seems you need simple ```UPDATE user SET employee=87847894 WHERE employee=35345642;```...